# Deleting a token from ledger

Tags: token

=Can anyone tell me how to delete a token completely.  I want to start over and use the same token name and home directory, etc.   but I need to remove my original token first.  I have all tokens in the issueing account but that account is locked.   Help???

Answer (score 1):

If you think the account is locked but it is not:

- Unlock your account

If an account is not locked:

- Transfer or burn all tokens except XLMs
- Remove all trustlines
- Use the merge operation to transfer the remaining XLMs into another account

If an account is locked:

- Perform a 51% attack to manipulate the ledger or convince the stellar team and validators to implement an unlock operation.